# Wordpress two different Registration form

Tags: wordpress, registration

Any plugins available custom two different field registration forms.

For ex:
Form1 showing : Name, Email,Phone number.
Form2 showing : Email,  Address.

Or any code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All you would need to do is create two separate forms and then link them both into the page or post where you wanted them displayed.  For example, if you were using [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/), you would just paste something like this into your page:

```
[contact-form-7 id="1" title="Form1"]
[contact-form-7 id="2" title="Form2"]
```

Comment: This is fine. But i want custom WordPress registration form. Not contact form.

Comment: It's possible? How to integrate this type form? Also this fields showing custom profile page.